# Symfony2: Custom Error Page Extend base.html.twig

Tags: symfony, custom-error-pages

I am trying to customize the error pages in Symfony.

This is my `error.html.twig` file located in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/`:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

<h1>{{ status_code }}: {{ status_text }}</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in
>   [...]
>   vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php
>   on line 144

When I remove `{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}` everything works fine. Any ideas how to have my base template included in the error page?

**Edit 1:**
The strange thing is that it seems to work when a 403 is thrown, e.g., when I access `/user` but don't have the necessary privilege.

**Edit 2:**
I pasted the whole content of my `base.html.twig` into the `error.html.twig` file and noticed that the error was caused due to the menu rendered by the `KnpMenuBundle` bundle:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('ACMEMemberBundle:Builder:mainMenu', { 'style': 'pills', 'currentClass': 'active' }) }}
```

When I remove this line, everything works fine. But this is not the way I would like to go. Is there no possibility to keep the navigation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634961/how-to-show-customized-404-error-page-symfony2

Comment: @abbiya Thanks for your comment. If you are referring to the production environment, I am actually running my application in the production mode.

Comment: I had a similar issue. The problem there was using `path` with the current request's route. 404 error does not have a route.

Answer (score 1):

file should be located in `app/Resources/views/Exception/`

instead of

`app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/`

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the page in the following place?

/app/ResourceS/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
{%trans%}errors.404{%endtrans%}
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// app/Resouces/views/base.html.twig

×
{% include('path/to/include') %}

○
{% include('::path/to/include') %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally have done it putting the whole code (base+current) in the same 'error.html.twig' file.

It works for me and avoided a huge headache.

Answer (score 0):

plz remove **::** in first line https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html

```
 {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

<h1>{{ status_code }}: {{ status_text }}</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question doesnt have an accepted answer. But the answer to this question is in the comments under original post by mark.sagikazar.

If your error404 crashes after you put

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
```

into your error404.html.twig with error saying:

```
Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension::getPath(): Argument #1 ($name) must be of type string, null given, called in
```

Then the problem lies in the base.html.twig. In my case it was

```
app.request.attributes.get('_route')
```

Because like mark.sagikazar said there is no route in error 404 nor other error messages.

So i just put an if statement around this code like this:

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}
.. do something here that doesnt work in error404.html twig
{% endif %}
```