# Symfony2 Custom Error 404 page

Tags: php, symfony

I am making a custom 404 page in symfony2. 
I already have a custom page that's working but when i extend the base.html.twig i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in C:\htdocs\pdb\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php:267 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\htdocs\pdb\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1361): appProdUrlMatcher->match('/test23') 
#1 C:\htdocs\pdb\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1254): Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#2 C:\htdocs\pdb\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1961): Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#3 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) 
#4 C:\htdocs\pdb\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1747): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) in C:\htdocs\pdb\app\cache\prod\classes.php on line 1977
```

I hope somebody can help me!

Comment: `cache` error; you cleaned `prod` cache?

Comment: Yes i cleared the cache, still got the error. if i remove the base.html.twig it is working fine.

Comment: Where is your `base.html.twig` page? `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig` ? How do you extend it? `{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}` ?

Comment: We need to know what's in your base.html.twig. Could be that it's referring to a resource that's not yet available at this stage. See this related post for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111807/symfony2-custom-error-page-extend-base-html-twig

Comment: Path to my base.html.twig : app/Resources/views/base.html.twig
I extend the base this way : {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

My code in the custom 404 :



{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    <p>Test my 404 page :)</p>
{% endblock %}

Comment: Seems to me, inside your `base` template you got smth like `{{ path('wrong_route') }}` where `wrong_route` doesn't exists.