# Symfony 2 EventListener Template

Tags: php, symfony

Hello i have made an eventlistener but now i want to return a custom template if there is a 404 exception.

I don't know how to return a template from an eventlistener.

my code :

```
<?php

namespace Pdb\Prodacom\EventBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;


class PdbCustomListener {
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();

    if($exception->getStatusCode() == '404') {
        //RETURN A CUSTOM TEMPLATE HIER
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create customized error pages in Symfony without the need of any event listeners

[How to customize Error Pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html)

But if you insist on using an event listener, you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034187/symfony2-change-rendered-view-with-a-listener).

Comment: That is true. However that is not working for me. 

See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076883/symfony2-custom-error-404-page

Comment: @Tommie Sorry for being late, Have you figured it out?

Comment: @Rafeal No problem. Not figured out yet. Any ideas how to do this ?