# Custom error pages for 404 and 500 statuses

Tags: php, symfony

I want to have different error pages for 404 and 500 errors. How can I do that?

I work in production environment only. I overrided twig error templates and put them in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` folder.

I wanted to create two files there:

```
error404.html.twig
exception_full.html.twig
```

This way if it's 404 it would open the first file, and in any other case it would open the other one.

I have a couple of problems though:

- the first file never opens on 404 error...only the second, and symfony default if it doesn't exist
- I can't extend the base template in neither of them (`{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}`), because if I use it the template just doesn't load

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12675355/4074148 custom error pages are only displayed in prod env. Have you tested in prod env to see if you see custom pages?

Comment: As I said, I do use prod env ;)

Comment: Strange thing is that using `extends '::base.html.twig'` disables the custom error.

Answer (score 0):

change your `exception_full.html.twig` file name to just `error.html.twig`.  It is working for me like this.  I have several `error4xx` files, and if I haven't defined a specific code and that exception occurs, it will display the `error.html.twig` view.

As for not showing your base template, where exactly is your base template located?  If you are using the syntax `'::layout.html.twig'` then layout.html.twig must be located at `app/Resources/views/layout.html.twig`.  If that is the case, then you should get an error that explains why it won't load.

take a look at the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#how-the-template-for-the-error-and-exception-pages-is-selected) for a bit more info.

Comment: `layout.html.file` is in the right place, that's why I think it's strange. Also, custom twig functions block exception handling.

Comment: Oh, I got it! It doesn't handle exceptions, because there's `app.user.username` variable inside the layout template. Why does that happen?

Comment: if no user is logged in, having `app.user.username` will always throw an exception.  you should have an `if` statement there, something like `{% if app.user %} app.user.username {% endif %}`